# How do you use Devise to register a User with additional attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Devise, and I have a `User` model. By default, there's just a sign up form with an email and a password. I want to add more attributes. For example a `college` attribute.

I've been following [this blog post](http://howilearnedrails.wordpress.com/2013/12/27/how-to-override-and-customize-the-devise-controller-in-rails/comment-page-1/) to help. I have a `RegistrationsController` that overrides the default `RegistrationsController`:

```
class MyDevise::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    super
    resource.college = params[:resource][:college]
    resource.save
  end
end
```

However, I don't know how to update the user. I've been looking through [Devise's RegistrationController](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb), but I can't seem to figure it out. Does it not have access to `params[:resource]` from the form?

This is the form in the view file:

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :college %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :college %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Comment: You should just add these fields to the views under devise/registrations, and add them to the model of course. No need to alter the controllers though! This will all go "automatic"!

Comment: @Danny Are you sure? I have the field in `/devise/registration/new.html.erb` and in the model. When I created the user, I looked in the console, and the user had the new fields, but they were set to nil.

Comment: Depends on your Rails version. In 4.0, Daniel's answer is the one to follow. In 3.2 or earlier, you can rely on my answer. The only reason you would have to modify the controller is because of the "strong parameters" in 4.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the **[Rails and Devise](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-devise)** example application from the RailsApps project. For example, to add `name` attribute to the User model:

You can create the migration with a generator.

The migration:

```
# db/migrate/..._add_name_to_users.rb
class AddNameToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :name, :string
  end
end
```

You need to override the Devise controller to handle strong parameters in Rails 4.0 (and newer).

The controller:

```
# app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :update_sanitized_params, if: :devise_controller?

  def update_sanitized_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) {|u| u.permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)}
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) {|u| u.permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)}
  end

end
```

The form:

```
# app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
<p><%= f.label :name %><br />
<%= f.text_field :name %></p>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Adjust the routes to accommodate the new controller.

The routes:

```
# config/routes.rb
RailsDevise::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => "home#index"
  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
  resources :users
end
```

Comment: I think you should accept @Daniel Kehoe's answer. He is  correct and one of the best rails people out there.

Comment: Vezu you're very kind. I hope the answer works for Adam.

Comment: @Vezu I agree! Thanks @DanielKehoe! I was really busy the past couple days, sorry about the delay.

Comment: @DanielKehoe BRILLIANT mate bloody brilliant!